# Adding swipe support in HTML5/JQueryMobile/PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, swipe

I'm working on a PhoneGap project and we want the user to be able to be able to swipe items off of a list.

JQueryMobile has events for .swipeleft() and .swiperight(), but those are boolean events; they either fire or they don't.

We wanted to get "fancy" and as the user swipes, we turn the item more and more red.  Once it reaches a certain breaking point, it will slide the rest of the way and fade away.  Then we'd use .slideUp() to close its container div, eliminating the empty space.  Alternately, the user can let go and the item will slide back into place, turning white as it goes back into place.

Conceptually I know how to do the animation, but is there some form of .swipeStart() / .swipeMove() / .swipeEnd() functionality I can hook into that reports how far the user has swiped?  If so, I can match the item's offset and color to mirror how far the user has swiped from the origin point.

Any leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Example

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K69AJ/

### Code

Javascript code:

```
var gnStartX = 0;
var gnStartY = 0;
var gnEndX = 0;
var gnEndY = 0;

$(document).on('vmousedown', function(event){
    gnStartX = event.pageX;
    gnStartY = event.pageY;
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('vmouseup', function(event){
    gnEndX = event.pageX;
    gnEndY = event.pageY;  
    var distance = Math.ceil(nthroot(Math.pow((gnEndX - gnStartX),2) + Math.pow((gnEndY - gnStartY),2), 2));

    if(Math.abs(gnEndX - gnStartX) > Math.abs(gnEndY - gnStartY)) {
        if(gnEndX > gnStartX) {
            alert("Swipe Right - Distance " + distance + 'px');
        } else {
            alert("Swipe Left - Distance " + distance + 'px');     
        }
    } else {
        if(gnEndY > gnStartY) {
            alert("Swipe Bottom - Distance " + distance + 'px');  
        } else {
            alert("Swipe Top - Distance " + distance + 'px');      
        }        
    }  
    
    event.preventDefault();      
});

function nthroot(x, n) {
  try {
    var negate = n % 2 == 1 && x < 0;
    if(negate)
      x = -x;
    var possible = Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
    n = Math.pow(possible, n);
    if(Math.abs(x - n) < 1 && (x > 0 == n > 0))
      return negate ? -possible : possible;
  } catch(e){}
}
```

This is my example that will give you direction and distance. Events used is **`vmousedown`** and **`vmouseup`**. They are jQuery Mobile events that are used to bridge touch events between desktop and mobile browsers, basically it will work on any platform. If you want only mobile platform then change **`vmousedown`** -> **`touchstart`** and **`vmouseup`** -> **`touchend`**.

Comment: That's almost perfect!  Is there any way for it to report progress as you swipe, however?  Right now it only seems to fire when you stop swiping.  For example, can you set margin-left equal to your swipe distance as you are swiping?

Comment: Awesome!  I tweaked it a little bit to be a bit closer to what I meant.  But I get it now - thanks for the example!

Comment: One more update: I tweaked it to be much closer to my goal: http://jsfiddle.net/2dA3g/8/.  Now I'd just have to have it animate back to margin-left:0px once the user lets go.